# Where to create htaccess file for a wordpress site hosted in AWS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services

Been working on speed optimization for a WordPress site hosted in AWS.
Created .htaccess in the root folder of the site added this

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=788400, proxy-revalidate"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Tested the site using GTMetrix, but it still throws 'Leverage Browser Caching'.  Seems the htaccess is not taking effect.  Is this the right place to put the .htaccess file?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Apache or nginx?

Comment: Hi Luke it's Apache..